# Can we change font of some part of a column's header text in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, fonts

I know how to change column's header text font. It's easy.

```
 foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgKisiFatura.Columns)
            {
                col.HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            }
```

I want to change a part's font of the header text. Like "March Sale ($)", I wanna make only "($)" part red and bold. Is there any way we can?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd have to draw it yourself.

Something like this:

```
private void dgv_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e) {

    if (e.RowIndex == -1 && dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText == "March Sale ($)") {
        //draw non-content portion
        e.Paint(e.CellBounds, e.PaintParts ^ DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground);

        //get size of text to write
        SizeF firstTextSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString("March Sale ", e.CellStyle.Font);
        SizeF secondTextSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString("($)",  new Font(e.CellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Bold));

        Point p = e.CellBounds.Location;
        //center text
        p.Offset((int)((e.CellBounds.Width-firstTextSize.Width-secondTextSize.Width)/2), (int)((e.CellBounds.Height-firstTextSize.Height)/2));

        e.Graphics.DrawString("March Sale ", e.CellStyle.Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), p);
        p.Offset((int)firstTextSize.Width,0);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("($)", new Font(e.CellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(Color.Red), p);

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, That code gives System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException. If I ignore it and keep continue by pressing shift + f11, it really does paints. Is there a problem the way I use that code? I picked my datagridview and created CellPainting method. And put the code inside it. Changed dvg to my datagridview.

Comment: It's probably how you are accessing your column array to identify if you're in the right column.  It might hit the paint event before all of your columns are created.  You can add a check for (dgv.Columns.Count > 1) or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can not set the same header with 2 different fonts - but what you can do is have a stack of 2 labels bound to your column